# 3rd party COM object cannot be serialized. Even if wrapped as a DataMember

Tags: c#, wcf, com

I am looking to pass a COM object into my WCF server, however  no matter what I try I keep getting the following error:

> Type 'System.__ComObject' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it
>   with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. 
>   See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported
>   types.

I have tried `ServiceKnownType`

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ComClass))]
```

I have tried wrapping it

```
[DataContract]
public class receivedClass
{
  [DataMember]
  public ComClass controlClass { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to serialize this so it can be sent to my WCF? (I am using this for an IPC program)

Oh, and this is COM class is third party generated

Comment: @AnonymousDownvoter Please let me know what I can improve in this question

Comment: No. Consider extracting the state of the COM object into a memento object and sending that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A COM object is basically nothing more that a pointer to unmanged memory. It cannot be inherantly serialized by .NET . However it may be possible to serialize the state of the object, construct a new object instance of the COM object at the WCF Service, and then restore the state. Properties of the com object that represent autonomus information can be serialized and passed up to the server. However, if the object is a wrapper for a any unmanged objects (handles, memory pointers, etc.) it may be very difficult to save the state of the COM object.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with the dynamic type and the COM binder that is shipped inside the Microsoft DLR. I think that could do the trick.
This is a nice post that  you may find usefull.
http://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/wcf-serialization-of-dlr-dynamic-types/